# Insert html div in js and take selector from it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML content of dialog with button:

```
<div id="dialogId" class="someClass" style="someStyle">
    <p>Some Content with buttons</p>
</div>
```

I need to insert it using JS and take div `id` as a selector for showing a UI dialog:

```
AJS.dialog2("#dialogId").show();
AJS.$("#someButtonId").click(function closeWindow() {
    AJS.dialog2("#dialogId").hide();
});
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').append('<div id="dialogId" class="someClass" style="someStyle"><p>Some Content with buttons</p></div>');

$('#somebuttonId').on('click',function(){
$('dialogId').hide();//to close the dialog
//$('dialogId').show();//to show the dialog
})
```

check this code